# Cant create Foreign Key between 2 tables with different CHARSET

Tags: mysql, symfony, character-encoding, doctrine, symfony-3.3

## Foreign keys across different Charset does not work

I'm Using Symfony with Doctrine to make a new project. But the old tables have the default Charset different to UTF-8. My new tables have UTF8 Charset. Resuming..
I have one table with **DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1** and a new table in **UTF-8.**

**UTF8** table has a relationship with **latin1** table. But i get the next error:

```
MySQL: Error 1005; Can't create table (errno: 150)
```

There is some way to make a foreign key between tables with different **CHARSET** ?
OR, Can i do it with ORM level?

Comment: I "solved" the problem with Doctrine, i can set the relationship at ORM level but i lost the referential integrity

Comment: "There is some way to make a foreign key between tables with different CHARSET ?" NO there isn't "Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must have similar data types. The size and sign of integer types must be the same. The length of string types need not be the same. For nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation must be the same."   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: I should have made a answer out off it annyway it was a bit off een answer comment annyway

Comment: i've added the doctrine tag for future readers if they get the same problem they can find this question and anwsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There is some way to make a foreign key between tables with different
>   CHARSET ?

On MySQL level no there isn't.

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must have similar data types. The size and sign of integer types must
>   be the same. The length of string types need not be the same. For
>   nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation
>   must be the same

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 2):

Wel, there is a way to do it, but is not at **SQL** level. If you can delete the relationship in your Tables because you are using **Doctrine**, try have your relatinoship in the **ORM** level.

Like this example

(A **Ticket** has one **User** and **User** has one **Ticket**. *One to One Relationship*):

```
class Ticket
{
 /**
  * @var \AppBundle\Entity\User
  *
  * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="adeq_user", referencedColumnName="id")
  */
 private $adeqUsers;
}
```

Then **Doctrine** get make the relation for you but the table is the same, so when you ask for a ticket you get the user that belongs.

**No matter the default charset on db**